# AMQP QPID client connector?

Tags: restlet, amqp, qpid

My next project is a RESTful application, so Restlet seems to be an excellent choice for implementation. However, I couldn't find any support for AMQP. What is the best way to add AMQP support, in particular QPID, to my project? I'm thinking of extending org.restlet.Client but not sure how to start. Any pointer is appreciated.

Thanks,
Khoa

Answer (score 0):

QPID is a implementation of AMQP protocol - an ESB if u want or a server that you connect to. Usually you get connections to it through JNDI, or AMQPConnectionFactory (if I am not mistaken the name). Restlet has to do with Servlets. I can't see the connection between one and another to be honest. For example with Restlet you can map a HTTP GET to a certain path, but what you do after the GET (for example connecting to QPID) is totally your business.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Since Restlet already had a bunch of supported connectors: HTTP(S), SMTP, JDBC, FILE, etc., I thought it would be more natural to add AMQP to the list. I guess I can manage the AMQP logic inside my resource, but it doesn't look "Restlet-ly" i.e. promoting re-use and separate of concerns.

Comment: Hello,Restlet can be integrated within a servlet container but it's not a requirement... You can use it standalone